# Outdoor climbing tour in/departing from Bangkok

Tags: thailand, tours, bangkok, outdoor-activities, climbing

I'll be in Bangkok for 3 days (and only Bangkok). I haven't been able to find any guided tours for rock climbing in Thailand that are based in Bangkok. I've only been able to find indoor climbing in Bangkok. I'm not specifically looking for outdoor climbing *in* Bangkok, but a guided tour that would depart from Bangkok and head out for a day or two, and then go back to Bangkok. Do such companies exist?

Comment: Most climbing areas are probably too far away for accessing out of Bangkok.  There are climbing tours (though mostly day courses) in the north Chiang Mai area and south in the Krabi area, but both are a flight or full day of driving to reach.

Comment: If you arrive in your hotel/hostel/... just ask it at the reception of a nearby travel agency, which of there are many. They will tell you what they can offer, no need to booking a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, companies exist (or, at least, existed recently) which provide guided outdoor rock climbing trips departing from Bangkok.

Two examples from a May 7, 2014, post on expatlifeinthailand.com (cached [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.expatlifeinthailand.com%2Frock-climbing-in-bangkok%2F&oq=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.expatlifeinthailand.com%2Frock-climbing-in-bangkok%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1913j0j4&client=ms-android-oneplus&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)):

> *Bouldering just outside Bangkok with [Proclimber Thailand](https://www.facebook.com/ProclimberThailand/)*
>
> A small purist bouldering club with a very small (and hot) wall hidden in the backstreets of Watthapra. In the dry season they have weekend trips to some great bouldering just outside Bangkok. Information can be found on their Facebook page.
>
> *[Bouldering Thailand](https://www.facebook.com/Bouldering-Thailand-323232944379224/)*
>
> A bouldering forum focused purely on the great outdoor bouldering options of Thailand, with trip to central and northeast Thailand. Just outside Bangkok near Pak Chong there are amazing bouldering options. Visit their Facebook page for more information

Comment: I added in links to the Facebook pages, both have seen activity in the last week or two so they both seem to still be going.